# PayFlow Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

We use on the site delayed payment transaction, like this:

1. Authorization transaction using credit card details including CVV2 code.
2. Get PNREF.
3. Use PNREF as ORIGID in delayed transaction.
4. Success

But now we got a trouble with recurring payments because we didn't store CVV2 value.

As I understood I can use "Authorization transaction PNREF" just for one delayed transaction as ORIGID. So I trying to get new one, but using ORIGID of previous transaction instead of credit card credentials:

```
TENDER=C&TRXTYPE=>A&AMT=29&ORIGID=xxxxxxxx7278&USER=user&PWD=pass&VENDOR=vendor&PARTNER&PayPal&VERBOSITY=HIGH
```

And always get an error:

```
'RESULT' => '117',
'PNREF' => 'xxxxxxxx20F8',
'RESPMSG' => 'Failed merchant rule check',
'TRANSTIME' => '2015-11-22 21:51:53',
'AMT' => '19.00', 'CARDTYPE' => '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to use the old PNREF to charge the customer is known as reference transaction and needs to be turn on in the manager account .

In your manager account go to "Account Administration -->Transaction Settings" . Here just select "yes" for "Allow reference transactions" and wait for an hour to get the settings updated.

It should be fine afterwards .

[image]